# DataSet does not support System.Nullable<> in Export

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dataset, export-to-excel, nullable

I was trying to generate a Report using Export to Excell, PDF, TextFile. Well I am doing this in MVC. I have a class which I named SPBatch (which is the exact name of my Stored Procedure in my SQL) and it contains the following:

```
public string BatchNo { get; set; }
public string ProviderName { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.Int32> NoOfClaims { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.Int32> TotalNoOfClaims { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.Decimal> TotalBilled { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.Decimal> TotalInputtedBill { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateSubmitted { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
public string RefNo { get; set; }
public string BatchStatus { get; set; }
public string ClaimType { get; set; }
```

as you can see some of my Columns are declared as Nullable. It went smoothly from searching and displaying the results in a table. I have several buttons below which are image buttons for export and every time I try to export in Excel, I always get the problem "**DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>**" in this part of my code:

```
foreach (MemberInfo mi in miArray)
{
    if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
        dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, pi.PropertyType); //where the error pop's up.

    }
    else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
        dt.Columns.Add(fi.Name, fi.FieldType);
    }
}
```

the error shows up on the one with a comment. Can you help me what to do? I tried adding  DBNull in my code but still I get the same error. I tried removing Nullable in my SPBatch but I get an error that some tables are need to be declared as Nullable.

What should I do?

Comment: I would suggest not using `DataSet`, as it does not appear to support your requirements.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

try with

```
dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
            pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType);
```

Comment: I tried it but I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in Columns[column].SetOrdinal(Index);

Comment: i can't see such code in your code sample in the question!

Comment: well on this side `public void SetColumn(string column, string columnName)
        {
            Columns[column].SetOrdinal(Index); //here
            Columns[column].ColumnName = columnName;
            Index++;
        }`

Comment: please ask different question for other issues in your application.

Comment: Well anyways, I resolved this already and your code is working fine now. Very much thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to a C# version of a generating a datatable and some hacking around, I can offer this answer in VB - I put it on here because I've just had a lot of hassle wanting to get a filterable dataset from a stored proc whilst using a simple datalayer. I hope it helps someone else!

Note: The use case is where you wish to use BindingSource.Filter = "some query string":

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Module Extenders
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function ToDataTable(Of T)(collection As IEnumerable(Of T), tableName As String) As DataTable
    Dim tbl As DataTable = ToDataTable(collection)
    tbl.TableName = tableName
    Return tbl
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function ToDataTable(Of T)(collection As IEnumerable(Of T)) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    Dim tt As Type = GetType(T)
    Dim pia As PropertyInfo() = tt.GetProperties()

    'Create the columns in the DataTable

    For Each pi As PropertyInfo In pia
        Dim a = 
If(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType), pi.PropertyType)
        dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, If(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType), pi.PropertyType))
    Next

    'Populate the table

    For Each item As T In collection
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dr.BeginEdit()

        For Each pi As PropertyInfo In pia

            dr(pi.Name) = If(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) Is GetType(DateTime), DBNull.Value, pi.GetValue(item, Nothing))
        Next
        dr.EndEdit()
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
    Return dt
End Function

End Module
```

Comment: This is great. Just what I needed. I did make one small change, which may be useful for others...
dr(pi.Name) = If(pi.GetValue(item, Nothing), DBNull.Value)
This seemed to allow it to work a bit better with nullable dates

Answer (score 1):

I would search for nullable and replace it with a string which can be null unlike a DateTime.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
{
    if (pi.PropertyType.Name.Contains("Nullable"))
       myDataType = typeof(String);
    else
       myDataType = pi.PropertyType;
}
```

Here is a complete version:

```
private DataTable CreateDataTable(PropertyInfo[] properties)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc = null;
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
    {
        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.ColumnName = pi.Name;

        if (pi.PropertyType.Name.Contains("Nullable"))
            dc.DataType = typeof(String);
        else
            dc.DataType = pi.PropertyType;

        // dc.DataType = pi.PropertyType;
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: So, what if the underlying data contains a DateTime in a particular row?

Comment: A nullable DateTime without value would be converted to NULL on the excel end.

Comment: Actually, I see where the answer added by dasmith would be more elegant.

Comment: How would it appear in the `DataSet`?

Comment: As a string, it would appear

Comment: @RossBush and if there is no null, but correct date, you'll get the exception with invalid cast, for example in dymaic request via Dapper.

Comment: This in my case worked a little differently: `prop.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("Nullable")`

Answer (score 0):

1) Define This Extensions as Below

```
public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> list)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

            //Get Properites of List Fiels
            PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            //Create Columns as Fields of List
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in props)
            {
                var column = new DataColumn
                {
                    ColumnName = propertyInfo.Name,
                    DataType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.Contains("Nullable") ? typeof(string) : propertyInfo.PropertyType
                };

                table.Columns.Add(column);
            }

            //Fill DataTable with Rows of List
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var values = new object[props.Length];

                for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }

                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }


            return table;
        }
    }
```

2) Call Extensions Method as Below where [_lstOperationDetails] is List that we want to convert it from List to DataTable

```
DataTable operationDetails = _lstOperationDetails.ToDataTable();
```