# LinqToSql query in Crystal Report returns SystemNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

TO-SQL` query I use to build a Crystal Report:

```
 private void Arrivages()
    {
        using(DataClasses1DataContext dc=new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var datas = (from art in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES
                         join ent in dc.ENTREES_STOCKS on art.ART_CODE equals ent.ART_CODE
                         where art.ART_SITE == 7 && art.ART_CODE == "A34815E1"
                         select new
                         {
                             art.ART_CODE,
                             art.ART_LIBELLE1,
                             art.ART_LIBELLE2,
                             //art.ART_EAN13,
                             art.ART_SIGNEQ,
                             ent.ENTSTK_LOT,
                             ent.ENTSTK_PNET,
                             ent.ENTSTK_DTENTREE,
                             ent.ENTSTK_NBU,
                             ent.ENTSTK_DATE_DEM,
                             ent.ENTSTK_USER
                         }).ToList();

            string reportPath = @"O:\GT\GT9999 - Applications\GL-T\Dossiers GL-T\Reports\Rapport1.rpt";
            ReportDocument cr = new ReportDocument();
            cr.Load(reportPath);
            cr.SetDataSource(datas);
            Cr_Viewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cr;
        }
    }
```

But when I run the application I get an error:

> SystemNot SupportedException : Dataset ne prend pas en charge System.Nullable<>.

English message

> SystemNot SupportedException: DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>

[image: Error picture]

How can i get rid of that error ??Thank you for helping me.

Comment: When you debug and step through, is datas null?

Comment: No datas is not null, but one field can have null values (ENTSTK_DATE_DEM)

Comment: Check if one of your classes is mapping a nullable field with a property that is no nullable. e.g. Database table: ENTREES_STOCKS - Field: ENTSTK_DTENTREE IS NULL in the database, but the class is DateTime and should be "DateTime? ENTSTK_DTENTREE".

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233295/dataset-does-not-support-system-nullable-in-export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wrote that the field: `ENTSTK_DATE_DEM` is null, try to replace the null value. You could also can convert it to a string and do something like this:

```
var datas = (from art in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES
    join ent in dc.ENTREES_STOCKS on art.ART_CODE equals ent.ART_CODE
    where art.ART_SITE == 7 && art.ART_CODE == "A34815E1"
    select new { art, ent }).ToList()
    {
         art.ART_CODE,
         art.ART_LIBELLE1,
         art.ART_LIBELLE2,
         art.ART_SIGNEQ,
         ent.ENTSTK_LOT,
         ent.ENTSTK_PNET,
         ent.ENTSTK_DTENTREE,
         ent.ENTSTK_NBU,
         ENTSTK_DATE_DEM = ent.ENTSTK_DATE_DEM.HasValue ? ent.ENTSTK_DATE_DEM.Value.ToString() : string.Empty,
         ent.ENTSTK_USER
       };
```

Don't forget to convert the field to string in on the report as well.

Comment: I've written : ENTSTK_DATE_DEM = ent.ENTSTK_DATE_DEM ?? default(Datetime)

Comment: But i'm getting an error because the returned date is not between the required values.

Comment: Btw default datetime is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`.